# Applying io.imread to Dataframe Column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe df with a column 'Poster' full of links to jpeg images. If I apply

```
img_data = io.imread(url)
```

theres is no problem because I'm using an specific url.

I want to make something like this:

```
x = np.asarray(io.imread(df['Poster']).tolist())
```

and get a numpy array of 4 dimensions (number of images, h, w, channels)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
posters = []
for poster in df['Poster']:
    posters.append(np.asarray(io.imread(poster).tolist()))
```

A fancier way:

```
posters = [np.asarray(io.imread(poster).tolist()) for poster in df['Poster']]
```